# $base64 encoded string from angular is not able to decode in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

**Client side code** (angularjs controller)

```
var p="gemüse8";

var pb= $base64.encode(p); // pb= Z2Vt/HNlOA==
```

**from server side(C#)**

```
string b64="Z2Vt/HNlOA==";

byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(b64);

string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

result showing `"gem�se8"`

How can i properly decode this string?

Comment: Whatever `$base64.encode` is seems to be using iso-8859-1 (or similar) rather than UTF - which probably needs addressing - as it stands use `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(data)`

Comment: @AlexK. that helps. Please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever `$base64.encode` is seems to be using *ISO-8859-1* (or similar) encoding rather than UTF - which probably needs addressing.

As it stands use:

```
string decodedString = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(data);
```